# Run build and tests in dockerfile vs on CI?

Tags: docker, testing, continuous-integration

the fastest way to run tests on CI is `./gradlew test` or `./gradle build`. it will download all the necessary dependencies (which can be somehow cached on CI), run tests and produce artifact (jar file)

i also want to build a docker image. some of the options i considered:

- build docker image on CI and assume that artifact is already there. it's the fastest way but ties the building process to CI. it can't be just build manually with 1 command (docker build)
- run tests as part of docker build. on CI it takes more time before i get info about failing test (as it has to download image, dependencies etc). but it allows to easily build the docker locally (probably rarely used functionality but useful for local docker-compose for tests)
- parameterized build to disable / enable tests by default

what's the standard way of handling those requirements? any best practices?

Answer (score 0):

Build the application you want to deploy in your Dockerfile.  Don’t include test-only dependencies, IDEs, source control tools, or anything else: include the minimum set of things you need to actually run your application and nothing more.  Don’t bother trying to run tests in the `Dockerfile`: it is only a packaging step, and you should have run tests prior to this point.

Write good local tests (in Java land, for instance, using JUnit) and make sure they pass.  If you need “white-box” integration tests that both depend on code details and external services, run them locally or in your CI system, but outside of Docker.

Minimize the differences between “production” and “developer” setups.  Ideally there are no code changes at all, and the only configuration changes are things like database hostnames.

Run full end-to-end tests using your Docker-based setup.  This step might involve running Docker Compose in Jenkins (slightly hairy).  It is a “black-box” test that communicates only with the service’s UI or external APIs.  The tests may or may not live in the source tree, but they aren’t built into the Docker container.  It might be easier to launch tools like Selenium outside of Docker space too, judging from the number of SO questions on getting that set up.

Comment: so you suggest to run tests (and build as tests depened on build) on CI and then run build again without tests in dockerfile?

Comment: That’s one way to do it.  You could also inject built artifacts into your Docker build sequence (_e.g._, inject a jar file instead of source files).  A multi-stage build could in principle do this too, but if the tests go wrong it could be tricky to dive in and understand why.